# Is it possible to use am to make USB settings menu pop up?

Tags: android, usb

For now, I am trying to make USB Settings Menu pop up in notification area without a usb cable plug in. However when I try to use adb shell am, I got a permission denied. So is there any possible way to do this?
I used this command:
`am start -n com.android.settings/com.android.settings.deviceinfo.UsbModeChooserActivity`

Comment: try command with sudo

Comment: I got another idea to do this ,but I do not know the right command line, I think it should be ok to use sendevent to fake a uevent reported from kernel to framework, so usb framework would believe that a usb cable pluged in.  Can anyone give me some advice about the sendevent command param?